# DEVEXPRESS - bind data to an object

Tags: data-binding, devexpress

Is it possible to bind a datagrid to an object rather than a datasource? We have a method that runs a stored procedure and then returns data within an object. I want to bind this data object to a devexpress control.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In c# or .net in particular, yes

Comment: which platform and what exactly control are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following article may be of help to you: [Binding Controls to Data Created at Runtime](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2387)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can implement in your object the necessary interfaces (IList,ITypedList) and provide access to returned data. For example I suggest you review [this example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E1075) that demonstrates how to use this approach to bind a grid for 2-dimensional array.

PS. For any detailed explanations or assistance in this regard I suggest you use the [Official DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=question). They will be happy to help you at any time.